# How to send data and redirect at the same time?

Tags: php

I need to upload the inserted data of the form and go to the Thank You Page on submission. I've tried some methods and I managed to only get one working, but not both.

The site on Wordpress and XAMPP. The following code just redirects, but if I remove the onsubmit attribute it will submit but won't redirect.

```
<script>
   function redirect(){
       window.location.replace("localhost/concurs/thank-you-page");
       return false;
   }
</script>

<?php
      $x=new mysqli("localhost", "root", "");
      if ($x->connect_error) {
          die("Connection failed: " . $x->connect_error);
      }
      $y=mysqli_select_db($x,"concurs");
      $Prenume = "";
      $Nume = "";
      $email = "";
      $tel = "";
      $Prenume= isset($_POST['firstname']) ? $_POST['firstname'] : '';
      $Nume= isset($_POST['lastname']) ? $_POST['lastname'] : '';
      $email= isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
      $tel= isset($_POST['tel']) ? $_POST['tel'] : '';
      $z = "";
      if($Prenume!=null && $Nume!=null && $email!=null)
             $z=mysqli_query($x,"INSERT INTO concurs.wp_formular (Prenume, Nume, email, tel) VALUES ('$Prenume', '$Nume','$email', '$tel')");
      mysqli_close($x);
      ?>

<form data-validate="parsley" data-parsley-validate="" id="myForm" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return redirect()">
    <button type="submit" class="form_submit LatoBlack" id="submit"> 
Submit </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Daniel Bociat, Could you show your php Code?

Comment: You should redirect with PHP not JavaScript

Comment: header("location:thankyou.php");

Comment: You cannot do both at the same time, but shortly after another. Process the POST and send an Redirect header when done.

Comment: @sarbudeen I added the php code, sorry for the late response I was gone the rest of the day after I've posted the question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
$query=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `table` (name,mobile) VALUES('$name','$mobile')");

if($query){
?>
 <script>
window.location.href="thankyou.php";
</script> 
<?php
}else{
   echo mysqli_error();
}
```